# Is there a CSS property for 'expand vertically until you cause page/parent scrolling'?

Tags: css

I have a large 'intend to take up most of the screen' component. If content within in this component is too large for the component, I want the component to have its own scrollbars, I don't want the page or the parent to develop its own scrollbars.

The best thing I've got for this is to use a flexbox on the parent to achieve this:

(Open full page)

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  document.getElementById("something").classList.toggle("something-big");
});
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: stretch;
  border: dashed 1px black;
}

.body {
  background-color: #ddf;
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.something-big {
  height: 800px;
}

.something {
  background-color: #bbf;
  border: solid 1px blue; 
}

.footer,
.header {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="header"> header </div>

  <div class="body">
    body
    <div class="something" id="something"> something
      <button id="button"> click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer"> footer </div>

</div>
```

However, I'm not that comfortable with this solution.

If I'm developing this as a library to be used elsewhere (ie. I have control over the `.body` component, but not of the `.header` `.footer`. or `.parent` components), then I need to specify to them 'For this to work you need to make the parent a flex container'.

Is there a property I can apply to the `.body` only in order to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can play with:

- `max-height`: percentage (exmple : `80vh = 80% of viewport height`)
- `height: auto`, `height: inherit;`
- `overflow-y: scroll;`, `overflow: hidden;`

To style the `height` of each component and which one `scrolls`.

*Check the elements below the comments in `CSS`:*

```
/* CHECK THIS */
```

**Scrollig HTML Page:**

```
.parent,
.parent > .body {
    height: auto;
}
```

```js
// Get the button
let myBtn = document.querySelector('#myBtn');

// A function to draw boxes (more content in .body > .something > HERE)
function drawBoxes(){
    // Array to hold HTMl output
    let output = [];

    // Get boxes container
    let boxesContainer = document.querySelector('.boxes');
    
    // Adding boxes for testing (You can play with that to check for smaller space (try 3 or 4 ))
    let boxesInTotal = 40;

    // Loop to draw the boxes
    for(let i = 0; i < boxesInTotal; i++){
        let box = 
        `<div class="box"></div>`;
        output.push(box);
    }

    // Print the boxes
    boxesContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}


// Click on the button to see the changes
myBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    drawBoxes();
});
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* CHECK THIS */
.parent,
.parent > .body {
    height: auto;
}

.parent {
    background-color: rgb(24, 146, 173);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}

.parent > body > h1,
.parent > h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.parent > .header {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.parent > .body {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.parent > .body > #something > #myBtn {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #121212;
    color: #fafafa;
}

#something > .boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: auto;
}

#something > .boxes > .box {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <h1>Body</h1>
        <div id="something">
            <button id="myBtn">Click</button>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Scrolling .body:***

```js
// Get the button
let myBtn = document.querySelector('#myBtn');

// A function to draw boxes (more content in .body > .something > HERE)
function drawBoxes(){
    // Array to hold HTMl output
    let output = [];

    // Get boxes container
    let boxesContainer = document.querySelector('.boxes');
    
    // Adding boxes for testing
    let boxesInTotal = 40;

    // Loop to draw the boxes
    for(let i = 0; i < boxesInTotal; i++){
        let box = 
        `<div class="box"></div>`;
        output.push(box);
    }

    // Print the boxes
    boxesContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}


// Click on the button to see the changes
myBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    drawBoxes();
});
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* CHECK THIS */
body {
    height: 2000px;
}

.parent {
    background-color: rgb(24, 146, 173);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

.parent > body > h1,
.parent > h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.parent > .header {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* CHECK THIS */
.parent > .body {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    max-height: 70vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
/* CHECK THIS */
.parent > .body > #something {
    height: inherit;
}


.parent > .body > #something > #myBtn {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #121212;
    color: #fafafa;
}

#something > .boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#something > .boxes > .box {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <h1>Body</h1>
        <div id="something">
            <button id="myBtn">Click</button>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Scrolling .parent:**

```js
// Get the button
let myBtn = document.querySelector('#myBtn');

// A function to draw boxes (more content in .body > .something > HERE)
function drawBoxes(){
    // Array to hold HTMl output
    let output = [];

    // Get boxes container
    let boxesContainer = document.querySelector('.boxes');
    
    // Adding boxes for testing
    let boxesInTotal = 40;

    // Loop to draw the boxes
    for(let i = 0; i < boxesInTotal; i++){
        let box = 
        `<div class="box"></div>`;
        output.push(box);
    }

    // Print the boxes
    boxesContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}


// Click on the button to see the changes
myBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    drawBoxes();
});
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* CHECK THIS */
.parent {
    background-color: rgb(24, 146, 173);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    max-height: 90vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.parent > body > h1,
.parent > h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.parent > .header {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.parent > .body {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.parent > .body > #something > #myBtn {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #121212;
    color: #fafafa;
}

#something > .boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#something > .boxes > .box {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <h1>Body</h1>
        <div id="something">
            <button id="myBtn">Click</button>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Scrolling #something:**

```js
// Get the button
let myBtn = document.querySelector('#myBtn');

// A function to draw boxes (more content in .body > .something > HERE)
function drawBoxes(){
    // Array to hold HTMl output
    let output = [];

    // Get boxes container
    let boxesContainer = document.querySelector('.boxes');
    
    // Adding boxes for testing
    let boxesInTotal = 40;

    // Loop to draw the boxes
    for(let i = 0; i < boxesInTotal; i++){
        let box = 
        `<div class="box"></div>`;
        output.push(box);
    }

    // Print the boxes
    boxesContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}


// Click on the button to see the changes
myBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    drawBoxes();
});
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* CHECK THIS */
.parent {
    background-color: rgb(24, 146, 173);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

.parent > body > h1,
.parent > h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.parent > .header {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* CHECK THIS */
.parent > .body {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    max-height: 70vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* CHECK THIS */
.parent > .body > #something {
    max-height: inherit;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.parent > .body > #something > #myBtn {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #121212;
    color: #fafafa;
}

#something > .boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#something > .boxes > .box {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <h1>Body</h1>
        <div id="something">
            <button id="myBtn">Click</button>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, so I think the use of vh is pretty reasonable here, where basically it's a kind of estimate where you would say "We think this component should take up about 70% of the vertical height of the page" - if there is additional content after this compoennt, then ofcourse it would start scrolling. Presumably then it's up to the user of the component to override that vh value to suit.